# Ways to represent function with multi-dimensional array parameters

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, parameters, arguments

I'm currently learning function that work with multi-dimensional array in C.

Let's say I have

```
short myArray[10][30].
```

I have declared following function prototype to work with `myArray`.

```
void first(int n, short ar[][30]);
void second(int n, short ar[30]);
void third(int n, short (*ar)[30]);
```

My understanding is that the `ar` parameter in both `first` and `third` function are equivalent. `short ar[][30]` in `first` function is equivalent to the `short (*ar)[30]` in `third` function because they are both pointer to `array of 30 short`.

The `ar` in `second` function is different because in `short ar[30]`, `ar` is a `pointer to short`, not a pointer to `array of 30 short`.

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes your understanding is correct. 1 and 3 are equivalent. And 2 is also right (But not for passing 2d array - it is correct for passing 1D array). But will clarify a bit the second case.

And the second one that 30 inside of third brackets are not considered by the compiler. You can omit it still the compiler won't complain. **Actually here you have passed an 1D array of `short`** that decayed into pointer to the first element (First element being `short` it is `short*`). So the second one you can also write as `short *ar`.

```
void second(int n, short ar[]);
void second(int n, short* ar );
```

These two works and they are equivalent in this context. ***The second one is for passing 1D array something like***

```
   second(n, myArray[5]);
```

The thing is, most of the time array decays into pointer (exception is `sizeof` operator or `Alignof` etc). Passing an array to a function is a case where the array decays.

Also you are passing `int` arrays so it is wrong to write `short`.(`int` and `short` may have same size but it is guaranteed that size of `int` would be larger than or equal to the size of `short`). If you used `short` and then wrote `int` in the declaration that would have worked.

**Edit**: The second one is not for passing 2d array. Let's be clear on that. You can't pass 2d array to a function with the prototype declared as the second one. For pointers there are 2 things to consider - it's type and it's value. If you tried to pass a 2d array to the same function that would be illegal. 2d array decays into `int (*)[30]` which is not in anyway same as `int *` or `int[]`.

Answer (score 1):

1 and 3 are indeed the same, as would be

```
void fourth(int n, short ar[10][30]);
```

because when you pass an array as function parameter, it *decays* to a pointer to its first parameter, so the compiler sees 1 and 4 as 3.

That explains why this would also be correct:

```
void fifth(int n, short arr[15][30]);
```

As it decays to a pointer, the declared size of the first dimension is not used. You are supposed to give the actual size in another way.

But this one is different:

```
void second(int n, short ar[30]);
```

and your compiler should raise a warning there because the expected paramater is a pointer to `short`, when you pass a pointer to an array of 30 `short`. Of course the pointers will have same *value* (same address), and common compilers will give expected results, but aliasing a pointer to array and a pointer to element is not allowed by the standard. So please avoid it.

With such a declaration, `second` should be called as

```
cr = second(n, arr[0]);
```

because `arr[0]` **is** a short array and will correctly decay to a `short *`.